# How do you automatically update a csv file in a Gitab Repository?

Tags: python, git, repository

I need some explanations or examples of how to perform updates on csv file in a Gitlab repository (with python).

I have a python script that sources data from a SQL Database, the script performs some functions and outputs the result in the form of a csv file (result.csv) example format shown below:

```
ID,1,1.0,0.0,0.3,0.01,0.04,...0.0
```

I have tested this out in Jupyter on my local machine and it works fine. The result.csv writes to location specified in my python script i.e. data.to_csv(r"C\Users\Ola\Documents\result.csv") and updates every time I run my python script.

How to perform the same process with the python script now located on Gitlab repo and the csv file will be written (outputs) into that same repo location as the python script (my Gitlab repo project)?

PS: I will eventually schedule the pipeline to execute once a week.

Comment: You clone/pull the repo, run the script, add and commit the changed file and push the change. So it's just basic git usage.

Comment: You should not check in automated changes into your repository.  Data files do not belong in a repository, only the code that operates on them.